# Can you use segment variables with the Pages Module?

Tags: segments, pages, page-uri

I have a very specific URL structure I'm trying to set up:

city-segment/venue-segment

ex. houston/the-bar

"city-segment" pulls from a City Channel while "venue-segment" pulls from a Venue Channel. I've got it set up correctly using the Pages Module, but now I'm trying to display a field from the City Channel using a third segment:

houston/the-bar/information

"information" segment should display text entered into the {venue_info} field of "The Bar" Venue Channel Entry. I have an info template within the venue template group with this code:

```
{exp:channel:entries
  channel="venues"
  disable="categories|member_data|pagination"
  dynamic="no"
  limit="1"
  require_entry="yes"
  status="open"
  url_title="{segment_2}"
}

  {venue_info}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Trying to view this code gives me nothing. I'm guessing that assigning a Channel Entry to a URI using the Pages Module is preventing me from using any segment variables? If so, is there another way to solve this without using Structure?

**Venue/Info Template**

```
{layout="_layouts/.html-layout"}

{layout:set name="city" value="{segment_1}"}

Hi

{exp:channel:entries
  channel="venues"
  disable="categories|member_data|pagination"
  limit="1"
  require_entry="yes"
  status="open"
  url_title="{segment_2}"
}

  {title} Info

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [Resource Router](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/resource-router) instead of the Pages module. In your `system/expressionengine/config/config.php` file:

```
$config['resource_router'] = array(
    ':any/:any/(info|menu|hours|some_other_page)' => function($router, $wildcard1, $wildcard2, $wildcard3) {
        $validCity = $wildcard1->isValidUrlTitle(array('channel' => 'cities'));

        $validVenue = $wildcard2->isValidUrlTitle(array('channel' => 'venues'));

        if ($validCity && $validVenue)
        {
            $router->setTemplate('_venues/_'.$wildcard3);
        }
        else
        {
            $router->set404();
        }
    },
);
```

This example assumes you have a `_venue` template group with `_info`, `_menu`, `_hours`, and `_some_other_page` templates. In your templates can you just refer to `{segment_X}` variables as normal.

Comment: Thanks Rob! Should I use this solution for the city/venue and city segments as well? Instead of using the Pages Module as I'm doing now?

Comment: I'm using the Resource Router in config as outlined and it is working, but it's not rendering any variables between {exp:channel:entries} tags. See above for what I have for the venue/info template. It renders the layout:set for city and "Hi", but not the content within the entries tags.

Comment: You probably need to add `dynamic="no"` to your channel:entries tag.

Comment: Did the trick, thanks! Now, I'm trying to take it a step further by using Croxton's "Multi-language routing with Resource Router" example, but instead using a channel entry segment. This way I could always ensure there was a city URL title in the first segment, but it doesn't seem to be working: https://gist.github.com/tinchco/bced087af51f2dfec71e

Answer (score 1):

It seems like an embed might help you get the job done.

Can you you do something like this:

```
{embed="_embeds/venue" segment_2="{segment_2}"}
```

Then in your embedded template:

```
{exp:channel:entries
  channel="venues"
  disable="categories|member_data|pagination"
  dynamic="no"
  limit="1"
  require_entry="yes"
  status="open"
  url_title="{embed:segment_2}"
}

  {venue_info}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you select the information template in the Pages tab?[image: selecting template]

Your code should work fine.

Comment: I can't since the content I want to display is within a field in the Venue Channel. It's not its own page.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like a good case for Template Routes - have you looked into that? https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/template_routes.html#template-route

Comment: I was looking into this, but it looks like the first segment has to be a template group name. With my implementation the first segment will always be a city name and creating a template group for each city name is not scalable.

Comment: The first segment doesn't have to be a template group name. So you could have a route matching /{city}/{venue}/information and then you could use {segment:city} and {segment:venue} in your template. You would proably also need to apply this patch: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20285